# Why won't justify-content:space-between; work?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, microsoft-edge

The items just stay to the left instead of spreading out. Also, I'm using Google Icons, and the icons won't show up unless I'm using the base tag in the head section (the domain name isn't registered); is this normal? My browser is Microsoft Edge.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Brain Archive</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <base href="https://www.brainarchive.com/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="brain_archive.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <span>Brain Archive</span>
    <span>
        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">search</span>
    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">menu</span>
    </span>
  </header>
  <main>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: flexbox only work with direct children. To apply justify-content on nested children, you need to add flex on parent element,

Comment: @Anilkumar this isn't exactly true nowadays. Flex can be made to consider the children of a child if that child is given display: contents - but check with caniuse that the types of elements you want are supported. It's OK in all major browsers for the example code given here. (Was never supported in IE).

Answer (score 1):

```
Make the Parent Span tag us, Div Tag.
 <header>
      <div>Brain Archive</div>
      <div>
        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">search</span>
        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">menu</span>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work perfectly. "Brain Archive" is on the left, and the icons are on the right.

```css
header {
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
    <header>
      <span>Brain Archive</span>
      <span>
        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">search</span>
        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">menu</span>
      </span>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a slight alteration to @BrettDonald answer - the icons are also spread evenly.

This is achieved by setting their span parent to display:contents which tells flex to include the children of that element.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

header span:last-child {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
<header>
  <span>Brain Archive</span>
  <span>
        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">search</span>
  <span class="material-symbols-outlined">menu</span>
  </span>
</header>
```